# How can I get data from two tables?

Tags: postgresql, java

I am using Hibernate and PostgreSql. In hibernate I have two classes like:

```
Mobile(id, name, serial no,model_no)
Model(id, description, value)
```

Now Model class's values are stored in Mobile class (model_no). This Mobile class doesn't have any reference to Model class.

In Model class has data like:

```
Modal
======
id description value
1  aaaa        1
2  bbbbb       2
3  ccccc       3
4  ddddd       12
5  eeee        40
```

Here this value is being stored in Mobile table. In Mobile table I have model_no as 0 (which is not in Model, I don't want to put that value in Model table, because if I put I needs to change lot of code.

Now what I want a query to get the out put like

```
value description
----   ------------
0     UNKNOWN
1     aaaa
2     bbbbb
3     ccccc
4     ddddd
5     eeee.
```

like this. To get the all `model_nos` I can use a query like

```
select modal_no from Mobile 
where modal_no in(select value from Modal) or model_no = 0
```

but here I what the description also which is in Model table. Can anybody help?

---

Thank u bro for your response, as i mentioned this Mobile table(Hibernate Mobile class) **don't have reference to the Model table**(in hibernate Model class). If i have reference to Model in Mobile class then your answer will be 100% correct. In my Mobile class this model_no is integer value. If i use your query in hql i will get the exception like "path expected".  I want Hql(or sql) query to get the output with 0 value.
my hibernate Mobile class is like this

```java
 class Mobile { 
   int id;   
   int model_no; // this model_no has 0 + modal_no values(1,2,3,12,42). 
   // some references like 
   Manufacture manf; 
   SerialNo serialno;
   Customer cust; 

  getters and setters 
}
```

My Hibernate Model class is like ...

```java
class Model{
   int id;
   String description;
   int value; this column has 1,2,3,12,42. it don't have 0.

   setters and getters.
}
```

Comment: No need to apologise for your English, it's better than my (insert your language here) :-) . It *would* help if you'd explain why the question is tagged `oracle-10g` when it's about PostgreSQL, though. What does Oracle have to do with it?  Did you forget to mention something? Please also mention your version of PostgreSQL; different versions have different features, so it matters.

Comment: Since your question is about Hibernate, it might help to add excerpts from your Hibernate mappings too, and mention which mapping method (JPA annotations, JPA `orm.xml`, Hibernate annotations, Hibernate `hbm.xml`, etc) you're using.

Comment: Where does the column 'value' come from in your:SELECT value FROM Model?

Comment: As i mention the Model table has columns like id, description, value. For Model table data check the above Model data.

Comment: I am sorry, my PostgreSQL version is 8.4.11 and my java version is 1.6.0_18.

Comment: I searched to know the exact difference between(JPA annotations, JPA orm.xml, Hibernate annotations, Hibernate hbm.xml), but i didn't get exact difference. I am new to Hibernate. Can u explain to me, other wise, if there is any link or documentation just send that link ill follow that.  Thank.

Comment: Can any body help to me, other wise give me an alternative solution please....

Comment: As this is really a Hibernate question, this should be taken to Stackoverflow

Comment: @a_horse_with_no_name I agree - I'm closing as off-topic and will see if SO want a migration (but even if they don't, the question is off-topic here and should stay closed)

Answer (score 2):

A `left join` would accomplish that:

```
select  Mobile.modal_no 
,       Modal.description
from    Mobile 
left join    
        Modal
on      Mobile.model_no = Modal.value
```

Comment: S left join will work, but i don't have reference in my Mobile table(in Hibernate Mobile class). If i use left join exception will come like path expected, because i don't have reference.

Comment: Can any body give answer please. Give me at least an alternate approach